# Авторские слова, вводящие прямую речь

Tags: глаголы, прямая-речь

**«Прямая речь»,— сказал/говорит такой-то**.

Есть ли какое-то специальное правило насчёт времён глаголов в авторских словах? Или нет разницы? К сожалению, материал по этой теме найти не удалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее полная классификация глаголов говорения представлена в «Толковом словаре русских глаголов» под ред. Л. Г. Бабенко.
Рассматриваемая группа глаголов обозначена в этом словаре как «Глаголы речевой деятельности» и включает следующие подгруппы:
а) глаголы характеризованной речевой деятельности (76);
б) глаголы речевого сообщения (119);
в) глаголы речевого общения (50);
г) глаголы обращения (16);
д) глаголы речевого воздействия (55).

**А.** Говорить (сказать), произносить (произнести), ахать, бубнить, восклицать, жаловаться, излагать, лепетать, перебивать, твердить, шептать.
**Б.** Говорить (сказать), сообщать (сообщить), болтать, говорить, докладывать,
заявлять, извещать, информировать, комментировать, лгать, намекать, объяснять, отрицать, переводить, предостерегать, рассуждать.
**В.** Высказывать (высказать), обращаться (обратиться), разговаривать, беседовать, болтать, обсуждать, общаться, осведомляться, отвечать, отзываться, перекликаться,
поздравлять, прощаться, разговаривать, спорить, спрашивать, шутить.
**Г.** Обращаться (обратиться), называть (назвать), дразнить, звать, здороваться, называть, окликать, приветствовать.
**Д.** Говорить (сказать), произносить (произнести), сообщать (сообщить), врать, грозить, допрашивать, ехидничать, звать, критиковать, льстить, насмехаться, орать,
приказывать, просить, ругать, требовать, уговаривать, угрожать, хвалить, шутить.

Как видите, все глаголы представлены в **инфинитиве**. Время же глагола выбирает сочинитель текста — в зависимости от собственно времени повествования.
Чаще всего художественные тексты пишутся в прошедшем времени или от лица автора (3 лицо), или от лица главного героя (1 лицо).

― Нечего туда лазить, дрова раскидывать, ещё пожар устроите, ― **затараторила** она. [Фазиль Искандер. Время счастливых находок (1973)]
Мошенник этот, ― уже не владея собой, **тараторит** запальчивый калабриец, ― пустил в ход угрозы. [Б. Л. Пастернак. Апеллесова черта (1915)]

― Мы сами догадливые, ― **буркнул** в бороду Коротаев и начал объяснять человеку, где в Вологде находится Союз писателей... [Виктор Астафьев. Затеси (1999) // «Новый Мир», 2000]
Иду назад, а навстречу Нилин, мрачный еще больше, чем всегда, на филина похож, **буркает**: «Комаров накрылся». [Виктор Астафьев. Зрячий посох (1978-1982)]

[Глаголы говорения в современном русском языке: подходы к классификации](http://univers-plus.ru/files/1/1/2/1125/Na%20peresech_2016_2-3_articles_pd/15_%D0%A7%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0.pdf)
[Время повествования](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/liteditor59/vremia-povestvovaniia-5dc84cd208ffd321245bf662) (Записки литературного редактора)

Comment: Римма Михайловна, благодарю. Вы меня выручили)))

Comment: Всегда рада помочь. Пошутим? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llpXKVu3eLw) Римма Михайлова я.

Comment: ☺️☺️☺️☺️

Comment: Алина, Вы уже можете отмечать полезность ответов (треугольничек — ответ полезен) и интересность вопросов (это поощряет участников, добавляет репутацию). Участвуйте в жизни форума, не довольствуйтесь частным знанием.

Comment: Отметила ответ)